# Merge collection instantly and make a new collection with grouping

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Currently using MongoDB Atlas for a Timesheet system. I have 4 collections in it:

1. category (has the record of clock in types and staff roles)
2. employees (has the record of the staff name and a unique pin)
3. timesheets (has the record of a Pin with the clock in type and date and time)
4. users (Admin login details)

Data of employees is as follows:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "62cf98457"
},
"name": "Name Test",
"pin": "1234",
"role": "Sales",
"site": "Port Melbourne",
"email": "test@gmail.com",
"phone": "999 999 999",
"dob": "2022-07-10",
}
```

Data of timesheet is as follows:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "62cf98e47caaa2ac70fba490"
},
"pin": "1234",
"type": "in",
"date": "18-01-2022",
"time": "Tuesday, January 18, 2022 6:25 AM",
"image": "image file url"
},{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "62cf98e47caaa2ac70fba490"
},
"pin": "1234",
"type": "out",
"date": "18-01-2022",
"time": "Tuesday, January 18, 2022 4:25 PM",
"image": "image file url"
}
```

For now I am querying the employees collection if pin exits or not and if it does filtering in the timesheets collection which has same pin values again filtering them by date and then by types with time to get all employees timesheets details is a list with date.

This process is taking long for a query.

Can we directly create a new collections example employees_timesheets which will group user details and create an object inside filtering dates from timesheets collection.

Example:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "62"
},
"name": "Name Test",
"pin": "1234",
"role": "Sales",
"date": "18-01-2022",
{
"18-01-2022":  [{
       "type": "in",
       "time": "Tuesday, January 18, 2022 6:25 AM",
       "image": "image file url"
  },{
       "type": "out",
       "time": "Tuesday, January 18, 2022 4:25 AM",
       "image": "image file url"
  }]
 }
}
```

Comment: You can do an aggregation `$lookup` query on employees and timesheets collections matching on the common "join" field, in this case the pin. You can also specify additional filters within the lookup using the `pipeline` parameter. Having a single query with all the filters in it is efficient .

Comment: Have you considered making of view to handle this instead of creating an entire new collection? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/views/#:~:text=A%20MongoDB%20view%20is%20a,permission%20to%20query%20the%20view.

Comment: @rom I haven't tried Views. Even this was its working but the main problem is of time for a response. The way I am doing is taking 2-3 second to verify pin and getting the details. But for insert its taking another 3 second. Just want to reduce these respond time. I will definitely look into views